Hide/Smooth seams between repeating spline objects
I am trying to create a spline/curve unit mesh and need help figuring out how I can hide this seams between each segment.  Pictured below are screenshots taken from blender of the effect I'm trying to create, the base mesh before applying the twist modifier, after the simple deform twist modifier.
Joining the objects is not a solution for me and neither is creating a duplicate, joining the dupe and transferring the custom normals with the data modifier.
The intention I have is to create a single mesh unit that I can use in Unreal Engine to create mesh of any length or bend that blend seamlessly together, the length of which can change dynamically at runtime.
I would appreciate any and help finding resources that address this type of issue and how to hide these seems such that when I import the mesh to unreal I can use a spline mesh component to create seamless chains of any length and bend.




hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Well, your question is maybe a bit useless on this site, because the visible seam in the shading comes from how Blender handles these normals on unconnected faces, that it does transition smoothly between them. When you repeat those pieces with an Array modifier in Blender, you can make the seam smooth by using a Weld modifier afterwards which merges the vertices on the border. However you cannot export this modifier to Unreal. So what makes it useless here is, the solution depends on how Unreal handles discontinued surfaces or if there is a way to merge them... not Blender.

Thank you all for the replies, doing some more digging and looking at the normal at the edge I started to see that the issue was starting to be that the edge normal were not lining up.  And it dawned on me that @Gordon Brinkmann was right.  The best way to solve this for my use case was inside unreal.  Instead of applying the twist modifier in blender, I applied it to the spline mesh component in unreal and I now have the desired effect.  In theory there should be a way to solve this in blender, by aligning the counter part normal but I am not sure how to do so effectively.
